# JavaScript Query to get children similar to an XPath search

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm trying to write a query in Javascript that will look for patterns in HTML such as finding "a" elements that are child elements of a div's child elements.  I can do this in XPath with something like

```
//div/*/*/a
```

(Ideally, I would like to be able to return the top level divs here as well as the a elements)

I am stuck trying to do this in Javascript.  Something like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[*][*].getElementsByTagName('a');
```

does not work: [*] does not work (I was hoping it would search all direct children) and .getElementsByTagName('a') looks through all descendants of whichever node we are on, not just direct children.  Is there a simple way of writing a JS query similar to the XPath one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector):

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > * > * > a');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate XPath expressions directly using [`Document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) in browsers that support DOM Level 3 XPath or [`selectNodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx) under Internet Explorer.

```js
function evalXPath(expr) {
  var items;

  if (document.evaluate) {
    var result = document.evaluate(expr, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var item;
    items = [];
    while (item = result.iterateNext()) {
      items.push(item);
    }
  } else if (document.selectNodes) {
    items = document.selectNodes(expr);
  }
  
  return items;
}

var items = evalXPath('//div/*/*/a');
console.log('found ' + items.length + ' items');
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <span>
      <a href="#">one</a>
      <a href="#">two</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
    <span>
      <a href="#">three</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="#">four</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```